# Google Sheets Query Across Multiple Sheets Not Working

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the following command for a simple query. But its only picking up the first data range instead of both data sets.

```
=QUERY({'CLEAN FORECAST'!1:2500;'CLEAN PAYOUT'!1:2500},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4")
```

Only the rows from the first data range, CLEAN FORECAST, are returned. CLEAN PAYOUT data is totally ignored.

I've tried using select* instead of Col1...n - same result.

I am expecting to have all the rows from both data sets returned by this query given that i'm providing an array of ranges using the {curly brackets}.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: `CLEAN FORECAST'!1:2500` you've identified the rows, what about the columns? normally this might look something like `CLEAN FORECAST'!A1:B2500` - so, the first array might cover two columns. The second array (similarly adjusted) would also cover as many columns as you like, but you are only referencing the first two columns.

Comment: @Tedinoz, thanks for the comment. In Google Sheets you can the columns as a shorthand. Anyway I tried adding CLEAN FORECAST'!A1:D2500 in both ranges and it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: I've got a feeling that I'm teaching my grandmother how to such eggs but... If your data is `'CLEAN FORECAST'!A1:D2500;'CLEAN PAYOUT'!A1:D2500`, then in the query: Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 will reference the columns from `CLEAN FORECAST` and Col5, Col6, Col7 and Col8 will reference the  columns from `CLEAN PAYOUT`. So if the `query` statement is `select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4`, then you will only ever return values from "CLEAN FORECAST" and no values from "CLEAN PAYOUT". It's time for you to supply some sample data and a successful outcome so that we can each work with known variables.

Comment: Just in case, @MikeSimmons, have you checked if nothing is written in row 2501?